# Event emitter from dialog afterClosed subscribe to the parent

Tags: angular-material, dialog, angular5, eventemitter, zone

I want to emit an event after closed a material dialog but doesn't work (maybe because angular code is out of zone?).

if I try this, it works fine (the event is properly attached in the html parent):

```
onClick(){
   this.actionEmitter.emit(result);
}
```

But if I put this code in afterClosed event:

```
    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
        this.actionEmitter.emit(result);
    });
```

It doesn't work. No error shown but the event stop there. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I figured out the problem. It wasn't an issue of the out of zone.
The hierarchy of components is this:

1. Parent: list of item
2. Child: an item with **mouseleave and mouseover** to show the operations buttons that open the dialogs
3. dialog

What's happen was the dialog is opened when mouse enter in the item, **in this time lost the focus** and in html showOperations was false. The actionEmitter didn't exist anymore.

```
 <div  (mouseenter)="showOperations=true" (mouseleave)="showOperations=false">

      <!-- item something -->

      <child-component *ngIf="showOperations" (actionEmitter)="action($event)"></child-component>
 </div>
```

I've resolved with [hidden] instead of *ngIf:

```
 <child-component [hidden]="!showOperations" (actionEmitter)="action($event)"></child-component>
```